# Is there a one line way to remove dollar signs from a string via sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file and am reading it line by line. Some lines have dollar signs in them, and I would like to remove them using sed. So for instance,

```
echo $line
```

returns

```
{On the image of {$p$}-adic regulators},
```

On the other hand,

```
          echo $line | sed 's/\$//g'
```

correctly returns

```
 {On the image of {p}-adic regulators},
```

but

```
 title=`echo $line | sed 's/\$//g'`; echo $title
```

returns

```
 {On the image of {$p$}-adic regulators},
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash in your sed command when using it within backticks:

```
title=`echo $line | sed 's/\\$//g'` # note two backslashes before $
```

Answer (score 6):

How about using [variable substring replacement](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#EXPREPL1). This gives the same results and should be more efficient as it avoids having to invoke a subshell just to run `sed`:

```
[lsc@aphek]$ echo ${line//$/}
{On the image of {p}-adic regulators},
```

---

#### If you wish to stick with `sed` ...

You problem is due to the way the backtick syntax (`` `...` ``) handles backslashes. To avoid the problem, use the `$()` syntax instead.

```
[me@home]$ title=$(echo $line | sed 's/\$//g'); echo $title
{On the image of {p}-adic regulators},
```

Note that the `$()` syntax may not be supported by older versions of bash that are not POSIX compliant. If you need to support older shells, then stick to the backticks but escape the backslashes as shown in [Simon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8823282/115845).

For more details, see: [BashFAQ: Why is $(...) preferred over `` `...` `` (backticks)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Answer (score 0):

Since `sed` solution has already been posted, here is an `awk` variant.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '{gsub(/\$/,"",$0);print}' <<< $line
{On the image of {p}-adic regulators},
```

So you can do something like this -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] title=$(awk '{gsub(/\$/,"",$0);print}' <<< $line); echo $title
{On the image of {p}-adic regulators},
```

Comment: That's not the result the OP expected.